# Running migrations over multiple databases/Schema dump error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiple-databases, rails-migrations

Anyone have a workaround (without monkey patching rails) for the failure of the db:schema:dump part of a simple migration accessing the wrong database for a table? I get the error

**Mysql::Error: View 'database1.boxscores' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them: SHOW FIELDS FROM `boxscores`
**

When boxscores is on database2. The ActiveRecord model is set to make the connection and the app works fine, it isjust the migration that fails, and that only b/c of the schema dump.

Comment: By adding an Active Record connect I was able to solve this issue. It also turns out that the models for those tables were not overriding the default DB connection like they should have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer this since I found the answer and it might help someone. No one else answered, so here we go:

By adding an Active Record connect I was able to solve this issue. It also turns out that the models for those tables were not overriding the default DB connection like they should have been.

Comment: What do you mean by Active Record connect? Do you mean create a model for the view? I'm having the same issue and it's very difficult to find any answers.